# Can't launch Desura due to "Permission denied" error

Tags: 12.04, permissions, games

Nothing happens when I click Desura, clicking force update works but that does not fix the problem.

EDIT: I know am getting this error:
Details: Failed to execute child process "/home/neil/Downloads/desura" (Permission denied)

Answer (score 1):

Usually `Failed to execute child process` with `(Permission denied)` means that the program being executed doesn't have *execute permissions* set for it.

By default, files downloaded on Ubuntu do not have execute permissions enabled. One of the reasons for this is to help protect you from malicious programs (or non-malicious programs that you just don't want to run by accident).

If you're *sure* `/home/neil/Downloads/desura` is safe for you to run, then you can enable execute permissions for it.

### Command Line Way

Run this command in a terminal:

```
chmod +x /home/neil/Downloads/desura
```

You probably already *own* the file, so you should *not* need to run that command with `sudo`.

### Graphical Way

In Nautilus (the file browser), find `desura` in your `Downloads` folder, and right-click on it. Click **Properties**.

[image: Nautilus file Properties window showing check box for Execute permission]

Click the **Permissions** tab, and check the box labeled **Allow executing file as program**. Then click **Close**.

Answer (score 0):

check the ownership of the file.

```
ls -la <file-name>
```

You should be the owner of the file and have execute permission

Comment: Right now, your answer looks like it's saying `ls` will itself change ownership on the file (which is not the case). You may want to edit your answer to clarify exactly what you suggest the OP should do.

Answer (score 0):

Got something similar when I tried to launch a nuitka compiled onefile project:

```
Error, couldn't launch child (exec).: Permission denied
```

Of course, my binary file had execution rights.
After thinking a bit, I remembered that nuitka's onefile executables uncompress to /tmp directory.
Having checked how /tmp is mounted using `mount | grep /tmp`, I saw that files on /tmp didn't have execution rights, eg:

```
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)
```

The solution is to run my binary with another TMPDIR path which isn't mounted with `noexec`, eg:

```
TMPDIR=/some/tmp/path ./my_executable.bin
```